# Dynamic profiling for java program

Tags: java, profiling, callstack, call-graph, command-line-tool

I want to profile a fairly large java program dynamically. More specifically, I want to generate a dynamic call graph for one run of the program. Is there a commandline profiler to generate such graph.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try [btrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace), which is a diagnose tool for Java programs. You can get  enough information from the wiki page, and a lot of examples too.

Answer (score 1):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) can generate call graphs:

[image]

You can profile without using the JProfiler GUI, either by defining triggers or using the `jpcontroller` command line utility. Afterwards, you can open a snapshot in the JProfiler GUI to look at the call graph.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.